# Why doesn't Powershell System.IO.DirectoryInfo with UNC paths work as expected?

Tags: powershell, directoryinfo

I'm seeing some inconsistent behaviour in PowerShell Core 7.3 with variables of type [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] - the following works as expected:

```
$dir = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'c:\deploy'
$dir.BaseName # returns 'deploy'
$dir.Name # returns 'deploy'
$dir.Parent.Name # returns 'c:\'
```

But where the assignment is a UNC share, the behaviour isn't as expected:

```
$target = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'\\sharedhost\Deploy'
$target.Name # returns '\\sharedhost\Deploy'
$target.BaseName # returns '\\sharedhost\Deploy'
$target.Parent.Name # returns nothing, checking shows that Parent is null
```

I would expect $target.Parent to be 'sharedhost' as that's the parent of the Deploy folder,  but instead it returns $null.

I suppose I could temporarily map a drive to that share and use that mapping but that's a faff and besides drive-mapping might not be a robust option.

Can anyone please explain why DirectoryInfo doesn't appear to work as expected with UNC paths?

Answer (score 3):

Your expectations are wrong. If you map `\\sharedhost\Deploy` to a drive, you will see that neither `sharedhost` nor `Deploy` will be a parent of it.

It is just how [UNC paths are defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/62e862f4-2a51-452e-8eeb-dc4ff5ee33cc):

> ```
> UNC = "\\" host-name "\" share-name  [ "\" object-name ]
> ```

In your case:

- `sharedhost` is the hostname, not a (parent) directory
- `Deploy` is the sharename, not a directory<sup>1</sup>

Everything else underneath `\\sharedhost\Deploy` will be files and directories. So consider `\\sharedhost\Deploy` like `C:\` in your thinking.

---

<sup>1</sup> `Deploy` may exist as a directory on the file server, but the share does not have to have the same name as the shared directory.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from @stackprotector, I've realised that I need to distinguish between local paths and UNC paths which must be treated differently.

Casting a full path name to type [URI] means that I can check if a path is a URI:

```
$pathUri = [URI]'\\sharedhost\Deploy'
$pathUri.IsUnc # returns true
$pathUri.Host # returns 'sharedhost'
```

Thanks again for all the feedback and help.